# Flex app needs to be worked in background

Tags: ios, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I have a task to create an application like an alarm functionality, means application also needs to be worked in background. When ever define times occur, I have to show some notifications or any related thing to user.

I have search through many threads and what I came to know is, background process is not available through flex mobile app for iOS.

It would be great if any one knows the solution.

I have accessibility of flash builder 4.5 and 4.7 both

Comment: Most likely you'll need to use a Native Extension to access the background process functionality or build your app in a different technology.  If building an iOS app; that means Objective C I believe.

Comment: Hey ReBoog, In case of native extensions, which should I use? any idea?

Comment: I assume you'll have to create your own Native Extension for this.

Comment: Background processing will be allowed for ios in next version of AIR (3.9) if you can wait for it: http://labsdownload.adobe.com/pub/labs/flashruntimes/shared/air3-9_flashplayer11-9_releasenotes.pdf

Comment: @LeeBurrows - isn't it out? I have installed it in my one of machine for icon issuse for iOS 7.. Thanx any way.

Comment: @Naveed, 3.9 is available but its only a beta release atm